# Permission denied When deploy Splash in OpenShift

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, openshift, scrapy-splash

I run Splash in Docker local it log like this :

```
2023-12-05 09:16:41+0000 [-] Log opened.
2023-12-05 09:16:41.584101 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':657831265', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-splash'
2023-12-05 09:16:41.714545 [-] Splash version: 3.4.1
2023-12-05 09:16:41.838151 [-] Qt 5.13.1, PyQt 5.13.1, WebKit 602.1, Chromium 73.0.3683.105, sip 4.19.19, Twisted 19.7.0, Lua 5.2
2023-12-05 09:16:41.838292 [-] Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov 7 2019, 10:44:02) [GCC 8.3.0]
2023-12-05 09:16:41.838352 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
```

But when i deploy it in OpenShift ( in OpenShift when build i need grant permissions ( chmod ) for folder which app will write )
Here is log :

```
2024-03-05 10:22:42+0000 [-] Log opened.
2024-03-05 10:22:42.521061 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':86792419', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-1000930000'
2024-03-05 10:22:42.604099 [-] Splash version: 3.4.1
[1:1:0305/102242.610966:FATAL:credentials.cc(121)] : Permission denied (13)
```

Here is Docker file in OpenShift :

```
FROM scrapinghub/splash:3.4.1
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /home/splash
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/splash
RUN chmod -R 777 /tmp
RUN chmod -R 777 /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /etc
```

In the OpenShift after deploy if app will write to any path which not mount to volumn . It will be Permission denied. Please help me what are the paths that will be written when the app runs or how can i deploy it in OpenShift ?

I tried using PersistentVolumeClaims to mount to /tmp path and  /etc/splash path . But i still get this error